# Regular expression for alpahbet,underscore,hyphen,apostrophe only

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression that accept only alphabets,hyphen,apostrophe,underscore.
I tried

```
/^[ A-Za-z-_']*$/
```

but its not working. Please help.

Comment: Check out my answer. It also matches @ and numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. Try this:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z_@'-]+$/
```

OR

```
/^[\w@'-]+$/
```

Hyphen needs to be at first or last position inside a character class to avoid escaping. Also if empty string isn't allowed then use `+` (1 or more) instead of `*` (0 or more)

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[\w@'-]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
@'- a single character in the list @'- literally
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: In addition to that if I want to accept numbers and @ also.

Comment: thanks,it worked like a charm.I will grateful if u provide explanation for same

Comment: @anubhava bhai really salute ur answers...you are always top in users list and in reputation. i have just started my career. In stack overflow u r my role model..salute u sir...

Comment: @Immi: Glad to be of any help to the community. Best of luck to your career and I wish to see you also answering many questions here in near future.

Comment: @anubhava sure sir.. really i m trying to do my best in span of 7 month i have scored this much, but really i want to scorer like u.. sure sir one day i will do..thanks for ur response

Answer (score 4):

Move the hyphen at the end or the beginig of the character class or escape it:

```
^[ A-Za-z_'-]*$
```

or

```
^[- A-Za-z_']*$
```

or

```
^[ A-Za-z\-_']*$
```

If you want all letters:

```
^[ \pL_'-]*$
```

or

Comment: +1 for introducing the [Unicode property `\pL`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)!

Answer (score 0):

When using a hyphen in a character class, be sure to place it at the end of the character class as a best practice.

The reason for this is because the hyphen is used to signify a *range* of characters in the character class, and when it is at the end of the class, it will not create any ranges.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be :

```
   /[A-Za-z-\'_@0-9]+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (in Java):

```
String acceptHyphenApostropheUnderscoreRegEx = "^(\\p{Alpha}*+((['_-]+)\\p{Alpha})?)*+$";
```

If you want to have spaces and @ also (as some have given above) try:

```
String acceptHyphenApostropheUnderscoreRegEx = "^(\\p{Alpha}*+((\\s|['@_-]+)\\p{Alpha})?)*+$";
```